# angular bootstrap dropdown in a table cell

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to put an angular bootstrap dropdown in a table.  The dropdown gets cut off at the end of the cell.  In this image, 'Another option' gets cut off.

[image]

If I used a normal select/option, I get this (the dropdown floats over the table and isn't constrained by the cell size.

[image]

Can the same effect be achieved with bootstrap dropdown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you attach your `code`, there is not much we can do for you..

if it helps - link to a working example of bootstrap dropdown button in a table row

### http://plnkr.co/edit/x4b7JAVThMZddxwFHDNt?p=preview

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jossef.  I had a overflow:hidden somewhere high up in my code.  duh... :(