# the width of ngx-select-dropdown its not working using table

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngx-select-dropdown

im using table and the size of ngx-select-dropdown is too small? i tried css, but its not working

> here is my code in html

```
<td>
    <ngx-select-dropdown 
        class="ngx-select-dropdown"
        [config]="employeConfig"
        [options]="responseDS"
        name="officeDesc">
    </ngx-select-dropdown>
</td>
```

> here's my css

```
ngx-select-dropdown, .ngx-dropdown-button {
    max-width: 220px;
}
                }
```

> component

```
this.employeConfig = {
    displayKey: 'officeDesc',
    placeholder: '',
    limitTo: this._Obj.length,
    moreText: 'officeDesc',
    noResultsFound: 'No results found',
    searchPlaceholder: 'Search',
}
```

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360727/angular-bootstrap-dropdown-in-a-table-cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just give class `dropdown` to `td` where you want to show dropdown.

```
.dropdown {
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```